# Push notification when time is registred in pickerView

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a ToDo-list in Swift, and I made i pickerView to let the user enter the time the task shall be done. Can anyone please help me with the code to let the user get a local notification when the task shall be done?
Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for Reminders, LocalNotifications?

Comment: You need to look into https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/index.html this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-event-kit-programming-tutorial/ this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/ and this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/